# Need second set of radios to become enabled only if first is marked Yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm lost here... basically in the following set of code:

```
<td>RSVP: 
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="updateRSVP<?php echo $displayguests;?>" id="RSVPYes" value="1" <?php if ($GuestRSVP [$displayguests] == 1) {?>checked<?php }?>> Y
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="updateRSVP<?php echo $displayguests;?>" id="RSVPNo" value="0" <?php if ($GuestRSVP [$displayguests] == 0) {?>checked<?php }?>> N
            </label>
            </td>
```

If they select Yes, I need the second set of code to have the disabled tag removed (aka it becomes selectable) and vice-versa if they select no above (disabled need to be there):

```
<tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="updatemeal<?php echo $displayguests;?>" id="Steak" value="Steak" <?php if ($GuestSteak [$displayguests] == 1) {?>checked<?php }?> disabled> Steak
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="updatemeal<?php echo $displayguests;?>" id="Chicken" value="Chicken" <?php if ($GuestChicken [$displayguests] == 1) {?>checked<?php }?> disabled> Chicken
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="updatemeal<?php echo $displayguests;?>" id="Kid" value="Kid" <?php if ($GuestKid [$displayguests] == 1) {?>checked<?php }?> disabled> Kid's Meal
            </label>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an `onchange` event to your `Y` and `N` radio buttons and based on their value add or remove attribute of corresponding radio button to enable and disable it. Below is the snippet for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='updateRSVP']").on('change', function() { //on change event
    if ($(this).val() == 1) //If value is 1, i.e Y is selected 
       $("input[name='updatemeal']").removeAttr('disabled'); //remove disabled attribute
    else
       $("input[name='updatemeal']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');//add it
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>RSVP:
  <label class="radio-inline">
     <input type="radio" name="updateRSVP" id="RSVPYes" value="1"> Y
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
     <input type="radio" name="updateRSVP" id="RSVPNo" value="0"> N
  </label>
</td>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="updatemeal" id="Steak" value="Steak" disabled> Steak
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="updatemeal" id="Chicken" value="Chicken" disabled> Chicken
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="updatemeal" id="Kid" value="Kid" disabled> Kid's Meal
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)